# How to overlay rows of Android Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to implement the below Android ListView. The each yellow box represents one row of ListView. If you see the rows, each row is over lapped by previous and next row. I have searched Google, but I could not find any proper solutions. If anyone has clues, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Think outside the box.  Imagine this list not having the rows overlap, but just having diagonal lines on it.  In your code, set the Listview's divider height to 0:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
listView.setDivider(null);
listView.setDividerHeight(0);
```

Then create two drawables for the rows- one for odd rows, another for even rows:

[image]
and
[image]

(don't use these two images, as they are not properly/evenly sized, but create the ones for your specific list).

Then create an adapter for your list view - and in its `getView` method, set the corresponding background to your element:

```
@override
public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyView row;

    if(convertView == null) {
        row = (MyView)convertView;
    }
    else {
        row = ... //create your view - inflate or create in code
    }

    row.setBackgroundResource(position%2==1 ? R.drawable.row_odd : R.drawable.row_even);

    ...  //populate the rest of the row with whatever you need

    return row;
}
```

And voila!  You get what the effect you need (note, on this schematic the black lines represent the boundaries between rows - these are for schematic purposes only - in your final result you will not have them):

[image]

Finally, please note that if you want highlight on your "rows" when an item is selected, you'll have to implement custom state change listeners, which would change the background of the cell that's being selected and also the ones above and below it as to create the proper visual effect.

Comment: If you want to just have rows go diagonal (with "dividers" all pointing the same way), then you can achieve this much simpler: just create an image of your divider and set it as the divider drawable for your listview in the XML

Comment: Thank you for your answers.. I also thought the solution but for for current app, we could not use it, because the yellow area is one image and sometimes the image is changed. So, to implement that, I should overlay the rows. Is here anyone who could overlay the ListView rows or decide whether it is possible or not?? Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: @mooongcle I don't think it is not possible to overlay the rows.  The way android list is drawn is each row is drawn at a certain position, just below the previous row.  You can try playing with the margin of the row view (in getView of the Adapter) by setting the top margin to a negative value, but I doubt it will be possible.

Comment: @mooongcle The only way you may be able to do this is to create your own class, which will extend from the ListView and override various drawing methods to effectively take over drawing the rows yourself.  Then you can do pretty much whatever you want.  But I must warn you it's not at all easy.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but I managed to find a solution

In the ListView in the xml you can set a negative dividerHeight, it works for me.

```
<ListView
...
android:dividerHeight="-5dp" />
```

I hope it can help someone :)